# Heroku Deployment Issue - No python application found

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I run through deploying my heroku app (a flask application) and it successfully deploys. But when I try to open the app I get the below error based on the logs:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

The way I have the app structured with key files/directories:

```
-Root/        
   - requirements.txt
   - Procfile
   - run.py
   - MyApp/
       -templates/
       -static/
       -routesFolder/
       -__init__.py
       -uwsgi.ini
       -config.py
```

I have tried to do a few different things including adjusting the `uwsgi.ini` file where I had started with `module = app:app`. Below is my complete `uwsgi.ini` file.

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master = true
die-on-term = true
module = MyApp.uwsgi:application
memory-report = true
```

Below is my `Procfile` contents:

```
web: uwsgi MyApp/uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: In which file is your actual Python application?

Comment: @Selcuk The application is actually in the MyApp directory. Then it runs from the run.py

Comment: I don't follow; `run.py` is not inside `MyApp`. Your `module = MyApp.uwsgi:application` line implies that there is a `uwsgi.py` inside `MyApp` package with a function named `application`.

Comment: @Selcuk I updated teh Procfile to just point to the `uwsgi.ini` and then changed the uwsgi.ini file to `module = run:app` and moved that file to outside of the app directory to the root directory where the `run.py` sits. I am still getting an internal server error that python app is not found.